Use Python interpreter in Docker container in VS Code
I installed Django using Cookiecutter template for Docker and am using VS Code as my IDE. But opening Python files shows error squiggles as my default Python interpreter does not have the libraries installed.

How do I use my Docker installation of Python as my interpreter?

Your question is unclear. Can you explain what is the issue a little more elaborately? May be give a snippet of the error?

@NiazPalak By default VS Code will use globally installed Python as the interpreter and for instance, any libraries (for eg, Django here is missing), it would show the above error.
One possible solution would be to use Dev Containers. But I am looking for any simpler solutions if possible.
I would like to use my Docker Container's Python installation as the interpreter.

In my understanding, docker creates a light weight os virtually. I do not think you can use it's interpreter as your personal vs code interpreter as it will be as if you are trying to use a python interpreter in your vs code from another pc's interpreter. Which does not make any sense.

@NiazPalak Actually VS Code can run a remote interpreter just fine (and doing so makes perfect sense and is in fact common practice). But that isn’t even necessary here since Docker containers aren’t really a lightweight virtual OS, and you can run containerised commands (via docker run -it) that work/act like regular commands, so you could run a containerised Python just as you’d run a regular Python.

If your application uses a full-featured build system like Hatch or Poetry that manages a virtual environment, VSCode can find and automatically activate it.  I wouldn't introduce Docker into this setup and hide the Python interpreter somewhere it's hard to run.

You are right, I was having issue with starting the dev container for my project. After restarting VS Code, it seemed to work fine. So the issue is solved now.

@KonradRudolph My apologies then. I did not know about that. Thank you for clearing it out. I am not deleting the comment for the future reference of people who will face same missconception as me.

@KonradRudolph And also I had one question. You are talking about using it through ssh in terminal, right?

@NiazPalak The remote development extension uses SSH, yes. But there’s no need to use the terminal: the plugin can be configured and used entirely through the VS Code command palette.

Option 1

Install vscode-remote-extensionpack in VSCode.
Open the VSCode Command Palette.
Select Remote-Containers: Attach to Running Container...
This allows you to use the Python version and packages installed in the running container.

Option 2
Use devcontainer with dockerfile - https://github.com/waanlabs/pydev
